# how to force TinyMCE use inline style when resize image

Tags: css, tinymce, responsive-design, stylesheet

in TinyMCE when you resize image using image tool.

The source code that TinyMCE generated use `width="..."` and `height="..."` that is very bad with responsive css stylesheet.

How to force TinyMCE use `style="width: ...px; height: ...px;"` instead of old style `width="..." height="..."`?

Comment: which TinyMCE version are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Use `inline_styles` option in TinyMCE init:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        inline_styles : true
});
```

Reference: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:inline_styles

Comment: inline_styles cannot force tinymce use style="width:...px" instead of width="..." when you specify width, height in image dialog.

Comment: inline_styles cannot force use inline style when resize image.